# Bash couting using uniq an array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops

arrays are driving my crazy on Linux.
I two arrrays called x, y.
Those arrays contain one IP that repeats a crazy amount of times.

```
x=(182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59 182.100.67.59)

y=(218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 
218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 
218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 
218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22 218.52.41.22)
```

How can I count variables x, and y. Using something like uniq.

```
(IFS=""; sort <<< "$x") | uniq -c
```

But it does not work

EDIT 1:

Desired Output:

```
6 182.100.67.59

24 218.52.41.22
```

EDIT 2:

I have implemented this simple for:

```
for i in $x; do
            
            echo $i | uniq -c
            
            done
```

It prints out

```
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
      1 182.100.67.59
```

But the desired output would be:

```
15 182.100.67.59
```

Comment: What do you want to "count"? "Count variables"? There are two variables - `x` is one variable and `y` is another variable, two variables.

Comment: Hi there @KamilCuk I would like to count how many times on variable X ip 182.100.67.59 is repeated

Comment: On variable `x`? What for is `y` here then?

Comment: @KamilCuk there are two variables because x represents one type of attack DOS and y represents Phishing attack. So I would like to represent them as how many times an IP has tried to pursue the attack.

Answer (score 1):

First print the array values on lines.
Then sort.
Then uniq.

```
printf "%s\n" "${x[@]}" "${y[@]}" | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am going to try this solution! Seems like that's it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just printing first value. To read the whole array just add `$x[*]`

```
(IFS=""; sort <<< "$x[*]") | uniq -c
```

Comment: Can you share the script that you have used?